# mysql how to select the same column from 2 different rows

Tags: sql, mysql, entity-attribute-value

I've got a table like this:

[image]

I want to select like the result is something like this:

```
611766 | 20912 | gruppo-1_codice_articolo | 112509892 | field_5db85a4e1decf
```

Where the last 2 column are the `meta_value` column from `gruppo-1_codice_articolo` and meta_value from `_gruppo-1_codice_articolo`

I can't figure out how. Is it possible?

EDIT:

I ended up with this, and it seems it's working:

```
select distinct m1.post_id, m1.meta_key, m1.meta_value, m2.meta_key, m2.meta_value
from fiamgroup_postmeta m1
left join fiamgroup_postmeta m2 on m2.meta_key = CONCAT('_', m1.meta_key)
where m1.post_id = 20912 and m1.meta_key like 'gruppo_%' and m1.meta_value > ''
```

But it's quite slow. How could I speed up it? Is it slow because I'm using CONCAT?

EDIT 2:

I've found that if I join also on `m1.post_id = m2.post_id` it's blazing fast, probably because post_id is indexed. Also, I don't need `distinct` anymore. Also, I added another join (because I needed it) So the resulting query is:

```
select m1.post_id, m1.meta_key, m1.meta_value, m2.meta_key, m2.meta_value, p.post_title
from fiamgroup_postmeta m1
left join fiamgroup_postmeta m2 on m2.meta_key = CONCAT('_', m1.meta_key) and m1.post_id = m2.post_id
left join fiamgroup_posts p on p.post_name = m2.meta_value
where m1.post_id = 20912 and m1.meta_key like 'gruppo_%' and m1.meta_value > ''
```

Still, as you can guess, I'm not an sql expert, therefore if you've got other suggestions to better write this query, I'll be happy to read and learn.

Comment: Honestly, I would just query for multiple rows, and then sort it out in application code. Trying to pivot EAV data into a row as if it is stored in a normal fashion is expensive and not worth the effort.

Comment: @BillKarwin for me the last query is good. postmeta in my case is ~1.226.367 records, while posts is ~15.681and that query takes about 9ms to execute , which is fast enough for me. Thank you anyway.